# manage thread with junit4

Tags: multithreading, junit4

With Junit4, I tried to write a test (.class) that contains 3 @test and need to open the app in each test.

So in the function init that start the app and close it:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setupOnce() {
    final Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            //start the appli in the main
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}

@AfterClass
public static void CloseAppli() {
    closeAppli();
}
```

In my testClass: `TestButtons.java` I want to start the appli in each @test which is not possible...

Any idea?

Comment: It is pretty confusing to understand what you want to do from your question. Why are you creating a thread? Is it like you want to call the main() method to start your application? Can you provide more details?

Comment: in fact, in my TestButton.java , I want to start and close the appli in each test(@test) , but when I run the test it runs the first one by starting the appli then runs the next test without closing then opening another appli

Comment: so my problem is how could I start a test by launching in each test the software I test and closing it properly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you're looking for is the @After method. That's called after every individual test. @AfterClass is only called once at the ending of ALL the tests.

http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html